# Implementing Apex interface for Steel Brick package

Tags: apex, cpq, steelbrick

we are using Steel Brick CPQ. One of the requirements for us is to customize the product look up page. When I accessed Salesforce CPQ -> Configure (button) -> Plugins (Tab), there is a option to specify Product Search Plugin. It seems that I need to implement SBQQ.ProductSearchPlugin interface. But I could not find any documentation anywhere how to go about it. What methods it contains etc.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

with Steelbrick CPQ most often you will end up depending on [steelbrick community](https://community.steelbrick.com) for documentation / help / support..

You can refer the knowledge articles under Developer Guide in the community 
for most of the component references in the package.

here's the article for the Product Search Plugin

https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Developer-Guidebook/Product-Search-Plugin/ta-p/13626

Comment: Thanks Vamsi for your post and links to the SB site and the article. I tried to implement the plugin as suggested in the post. However I am getting an error 

"Error instantiating CSBQQInitialSearchFilter plugin: No type found for [CSBQQInitialSearchFilter] in namespace []"

CSBQQInitialSearchFilter is the Apex class that implements SBQQProductSearchPlugin. I tried to find out whats wrong with the namespace, without any luck. Any idea what I am missing?

SBQQ site doesn't let strangers register it seems.